# How to add glassfish 2.x to Netbeans 7.0.1 on mac os x

Tags: glassfish, macos, netbeans7.0

I have been trying to install glashfish 2.x into netbeans 7.0.1 for three days now. Needless to say, I have tried many, many things. Presently I am here: According to Netbeans.org, glassfish 2.x should be in the list of available plugins. But it's not there.

Will anyone please share their success with me? I am using mac os x.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tell me about it.  Been fighting this off and on now for a week.  Keep having to go back to 7.0.0 prior to adding the 'fixes' to plugins.  Utterly frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

Did you guys check what you had in your [netbeans update center](http://netbeans.org/community/guidelines/au-management.html#Autoupdate%20center%20%28AUC%29) ? I have heard people mentioning that they had URLs for 6.9 and plugins (such as GF2.0) will not show up until you modify that URL for 7.0